# How to match string using pattern and return custom output

Tags: python

I am trying to match strings in a column using regex pattern from below code.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': ['aa', 'aabc', '111aabc222']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

pat_data = {'name': ['aa', '111(.*?)222']}
df_p = pd.DataFrame(pat_data)
print(df_p)

pat = "|".join(map(str,df_p['name']))
print(pat)

# This one works fine 
df['col1'].str.extract('(' + pat + ')', expand=False)
```

OutPut:

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | aa |
| 1 | aa |
| 2 | 111aabc222 |

Expected Output:

I just need the combination of start and end string used in regex as output. How can i modify my code to do this?

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | aa |
| 1 | aa |
| 2 | 111 - 222 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not fully clear, my understanding is that you want to match subparts of the string. Then set the capturing groups directly in the initial subpatterns and post-process the output:

```
pat_data = {'name': ['(aa)', '(111).*?(222)']}
# ...
df['out'] = (df['col1'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
             .stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' - '.join)
            )
```

output:

```
         col1        out
0          aa         aa
1        aabc         aa
2  111aabc222  111 - 222
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Is there a way when in case of no match its populated as NULL instead of NaN?

Comment: You can `fillna` you column with `'NULL'` afterwards